# Problem in running Python Script (I am beginner)

Tags: python, python-3.7

```
 pip install -r requirements.txt
```

File "", line 1
    pip install -r requirements.txt
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: That's not a line of Python code, it's a separate command you run in a terminal.

Comment: Please can you help me by showing how to open it in terminal?.

Comment: What is the content of requirements.txt? Just to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to install the requirements for the Django project?

1. You could be running this inside a python shell. Try opening up your terminal and running it.
2. Check you have Pip working.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn all about the pip command here.  It should not be used in a script or the interpreter.

https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#requirements-for-installing-packages

and

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#requirements-files

That command you wrote should be used in a terminal or command prompt, as long as python is in your path variable (otherwise you must specify the absolute path of python) and the requirements.txt file is in the folder you are currently running the command.

`C:\> (#) python -m pip install mymodule`

mymodule must be a pypi package.  If you are trying to install the requirements of a package you already have installed or with a requirements.txt, you must either be in the directory of the requirements.txt file or reference the absolute path.

`C:\mymodule> (user@comp:/home/user/mymodule#) python -m pip -r requirements.txt`

And when you do post include the places you have looked and the methods you have tried.  As well as provide background, like why you are trying to install the requirements of a module?  What module is it? Is it a pip package or is it a custom module?